# Convert the dataype of VALUES in Maps Go language

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map in GO as :

```
var userinputmap = make(map[string]string)
```

and the values in it are of type :

```
[ABCD:30 EFGH:50 PORS:60]
```

Not that the 30,50,60 are strings over here.

I wish to have a same map but the numeric values should have float64 type instead of string type.

Desired output :

```
var output = make(map[string]float64)
```

I tried to do it but I get an error : `cannot use <placeholder_name> (type string) as type float64 in assignment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this by simple typecasting; the two maps have different representations in memory.

To solve this, you will have to iterate over every entry of the first map, convert the string representation of the float to a `float64`, then store the new value in the other map:

```
import "strconv"

var output = make(map[string]float64)
for key, value := range userinputmap {
    if converted, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value, 64); err == nil {
        output[key] = converted
    }
}
```